# Python django test case - one test failing when all tests are ran - Class variable data remaining during test

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, dictionary

I have a dictionary which is a class variable. One test will run methods which populates this dictionary in the course of the test. There is an if statement in the code(not the tests) which basically says if dict do this. Else do this. However when i run another test which does not populate this dict the dict is already populated with the old data,and hence the if code is executed.

How can i wipe the old data from the class variables

Comment: Don't use a class variable? If your test can fail because it modifies the variable, so can your code. Use an instance variable instead.

Comment: Yeah that fixed it. Can you explain why the data would be kept?
the strange this is that i old discovered the bug when i went to change a test name. I had a double underscore in the name by mistakes and it was getting executed before the other test and not causing a problem